# Why can't the jvm write to gpio on raspberry pi?

Tags: java, raspberry-pi2

I have a java method that looks like,

```
private void exportGpio(){
    String fullPath = path + "/export"; // /sys/class/gpio/export
    FileWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new FileWriter(fullPath);
        writer.write("" + number); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG + number, "Could not export", e);
    }
    finally {
        if(writer != null){
            try {
                writer.flush(); <- FAILING HERE
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG + number, "Could not close writer", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once it gets to the flush it throws an exception

> java.io.IOException: Device or resource busyjava.io.IOException:
>   Device or resource busy   at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native
>   Method)   at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:345)
>     at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)  at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)  at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)    at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)    at
>   java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)     at
>   lights.GPIO.exportGpio(GPIO.java:106)     at
>   lights.GPIO.(GPIO.java:34)  at
>   lights.LightManager.(LightManager.java:34)  at
>   main.Main.createSubsystems(Main.java:17)  at
>   main.Main.main(Main.java:34)

What is going on? Can java not interact with syses on a raspberry pi?

Comment: It is not bad to ask your question on the http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ directly.

Comment: I didn't know that was a think. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did end up figuring this out. I looked at STaefi answers and I think your wrong. The os drivers should handle the voltages. What I discovered was that the FileWritter class in java does not work well with these types of virtual files. I ended up trying the java print writer class and everything works.

```
PrintWriter writer = null;
try {
    writer = new PrintWriter(fullPath, "UTF-8");
    writer.write("1");
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG + number, "Could not turn on", e);
}
finally {
    if(writer != null){
        try {
            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG + number, "Could not close writer", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Im still not exactly sure why the file writers don't work but this solution will at least help anyone else that gets stuck here along the way.

Answer (score 2):

No it can not do it directly so easily.

General Purpose I/O pins are some `input/output` that we can put some `High` or `Low` voltages on them. Or we can read some `High` or `Low` voltages from them.

**They are not digital port interfaces** that we can write bits and bytes of the digital world into them directly. You need some **low level programming interfaces** to read/write on `GPIO`s.

These low level programming APIs can translate your `0` or `1` as some `high` and `low` voltages.

There is a very elegant library called [Pi4J](http://pi4j.com/) that you can use very easily in your code. They have a very good documentation which help you through working with Raspberry PI board. If you are a programmer from high level programming languages like java, it gives you the good flavor of event based programming with support of `EventListeners` instead of polling and interrupt for reading from a `I/O` pins. If you are not forced to work directly on the device it is very good alternative to work with.

Hope this would be helpful.